# How to return a specific exit code from a Mix Task?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm writing a Mix Task that is supposed to be as part of CI and should stop the build process if it fails, which is normally done using [exit codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html), where 0 code denotes success and non-0 an error. I would want to be able to return an arbitrary exit code to signal different types of failures.

How would I do it in a `Mix.Task`? The documentation for the [`run/1` callback](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#c:run/1) doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`exit/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#exit/1). For example putting `exit({:shutdown, 15})` inside your mix task will result in the following:

```
$ mix compile && mix custom.task
$ echo $?
15
```